# Initiating a call using Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I have found the way to send SMS using the Android.Telephony.Gsm.SmsManager class but for the life of me I can't find how to initiate a call. Is it only possible through an intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate a call only in 2 ways, using `Intent.ActionDial` or `Intent.ActionCall`.
Why the way with `Intent` is bad ?

```
var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:+56889554540154"));
StartActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Using Intent is not bad, it just seems inconsistent with the way SMS are sent (unless I misunderstood).